# Dictionary count with in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, count, nsdictionary

I am pulling a dictionary under NSDictionary that has sub-dictionaries within.  I have to display all this within a Table View.  Number of items, dictionaries are completely random....

```
 {
        Key = Value;
        Key = Value;
        Key = Value;
        “{Dictionary 1}” =     {
            Key = Value;
            Key = Value;
            Key = Value;
        };
        "{Dictionary 2}” =     {
            Key = Value;
            Key = Value;
        };
        Key = Value;
        Key = Value;
        “{Dictionary 3}” =     {
            Key = Value;
            Key = Value;
            Key = Value;
            Key = Value;
        };
        Key = Value;
    }
```

How would I get the count of sub-dictionaries out of this main NSDictionary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try to cast the value into a dictionary and if it works, then increment your counter for the number of dictionaries.

E.g.:

```
let upperDict = ["key":1,
                 "key2":2,
                 "key3":3,
                 "dict1": ["key1":"1", "key2":32],
                 "dict2": ["key1" :1]] as NSDictionary

var innnerDictionariesCount = 0

for (key, value) in upperDict {
    if value as? [String:Any] != nil {
        innnerDictionariesCount += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display all contents in one section, I think you need to know how many values in the main dictionary instead of how many sub-dictionaries.

```
let mainDic: NSDictionary = ["value1": "value1", 
                             "value2": "value2", 
                             "subDic1": ["value1": "value1", "value2": "value2"],
                             "subDic2": ["value1": "value1", "value2": "value2"] 
                            ]

var counter = 0
for (key, value) in mainDic {
    if value is String {
        counter += 1
    } 
    else if value is Dictionary<String, Any> {
        let subDic = value as! Dictionary<String, Any>
        counter += subDic.count
    }
    else if value is Array<Any> {
        let subArray = value as! Array<Any>
        counter += subArray.count
    }
}

print(counter) // output is 6
```